# Chrome extension to dim the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, google-chrome-extension

i wanted to ask a question regarding this chrome extension called [Turn Off The Lights](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/turn%20off%20the%20lights) , im aware of how to dim the background using jquery and css etc.. but what i am interested in knowing is how to get the current video playing from popular websites like YouTube, dailymotion etc.. before applying the jquery effects..?

Answer (score 1):

search with javascript to this "movie_player" id (YouTube only) and check if it's playing, if yes -> dim the web page.

More information about detecting the video player status, see this API link:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_controls

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what if i want only one piece of code to access the currently playing video on any video sharing website?

Comment: most video sites are using HTML5 video, and that is the same technique as the youtube API. Just get the ID of the <video> element.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that it looks for  or  elements in the page using some selector.

Then it would add the div to dim the background using a content script, changing the z-index of the found video element to a higher value.